# How to dynamically allocate, populate certain spots, and print a 2D array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, project, populate

I have a project to do for class, where the professor wants us to populate a 2d array and print it so it looks like this.

[Map Thingy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3Xkx.png)

The array is supposed to be 8x8 then 8 equal signs on the top and bottom. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

First use printf() to make the 8 equal signs.

Then depending on how the array is filled, fill it and then use a nested for loop to print each row sequentially of a 2D array `arr[x][y];` If there is a 0 or -1 (however you want to tell the program that that slot is empty) print a space.

Then Repeat the first step of printing the 8 equal signs.